# Pandas combine two columns with delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns which have delimiters:

```
column1    column2
a,b,c,d    e,f,g,h
h,i        j,k
l,m,n      o,p,q
...         ...
```

I am trying to group them as ae, bf, cg, dh, hj, ik,etc.

I can split the delimiters but I do not know how to combine these, any help would be appreciated.

```
saved_column_1 = df["column1"].str.split(',', expand=True)
saved_column_2 = df["column2"].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Comment: is the `.` in `p.q` a typo or expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [','.join(''.join(x) 
             for x in list(zip(a.split(','), b.split(','))))
            for a, b in zip(df['column1'], df['column2'])]
print (df)
   column1  column2          new
0  a,b,c,d  e,f,g,h  ae,bf,cg,dh
1      h,i      j,k        hj,ik
2    l,m,n    o,p.q      lo,mp,nq
```

If need Series:

```
L = [''.join(x)  for a, b in zip(df['column1'], df['column2'])
     for x in list(zip(a.split(','),b.split(',')))]

s = pd.Series(L)
print (s)
0    ae
1    bf
2    cg
3    dh
4    hj
5    ik
6    lo
7    mp
8    nq
dtype: object
```

Comment: For the series, I have columns that are fixed with just one value E.g. column3 has row1=1, row2=2, row3=3. I should get ae1, bf1, cg1, dh1, hj2, ik2. How do I get this?

I tried including it into the zip, but this doesn't seem to be correct. I believe the problem is that I don't need to split it so it moves on to the next value e.g.

`L = [''.join(x)  for a, b,c in zip(df['column1'], df['column2'], df['column3'])
     for x in list(zip(a.split(','),b.split(','), str(c)))]`

Comment: @Anderson - You can use `L = [f"{''.join(x)}{c}"  for a, b,c in 
     zip(df['column1'], df['column2'], df['column3'])     
     for x in list(zip(a.split(','),b.split(',')))]`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could use:

```
(df.apply(lambda c: c.str.split('[,.]')) # or split(',') if the '.' is a typo
   .explode(list(df.columns))
   .agg(''.join, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
0    ae
0    bf
0    cg
0    dh
1    hj
1    ik
2    lo
2    mp
2    nq
dtype: object
```

For a second level of grouping:

```
(df.apply(lambda c: c.str.split('[,.]'))
   .explode(list(df.columns))
   .agg(''.join, axis=1)
   .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)  # this line is added
)
```

output:

```
0    ae,bf,cg,dh
1          hj,ik
2       lo,mp,nq
dtype: object
```